# R: dynamic arguments

Tags: r, dynamic, arguments, parameter-passing

I'm using an R function which requires a list of variables as input arguments in the following format:

```
  output <- funName(gender ~ height + weight + varName4, data=tableName)
```

Basically the input arguments are column names in the table (and are not to be enclosed in ""). I have a list of these variables that I want to add one by one; i.e. run the function with one variable first, get the output, and incrementally adding variables (getting an output each time) i.e.

iteration 1:

```
  output <- funName(gender ~ height, data=tableName)
```

iteration 2:

```
  output <- funName(gender ~ height + weight, data=tableName)
```

iteration 3:

```
  output <- funName(gender ~ height + weight + varName4, data=tableName)
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

```
# vector of variable names
myNames <- c("gender", "height", "weight", "varName4")

# print out results
for(i in 2:4) {
  print(as.formula(paste(myNames[1], "~", paste(myNames[2:i], collapse="+"))))
}
```

Of course, you can replace `print` with the appropriate `funName`, such as `lm`, along with additional arguments. So

```
for(i in 2:4) {
  lm(as.formula(paste(myNames[1], "~", paste(myNames[2:i], collapse="+"))), data=tableName)
}
```

Should work as you would expect it to.  You could also use `lapply` if you wanted to save the results in an orderly fashion:

```
temp <- lapply(2:4, function(i) as.formula(paste(myNames[1], "~", 
                                             paste(myNames[2:i], collapse="+"))))
```

will save a list of formulas, for example.

Using the `reformulate` function as mentioned by @ben-bolker, you can simplify the web of `paste` functions:

```
for(i in 2:4) {
  print(reformulate(myNames[2:i], response = myNames[1], intercept = TRUE)) 
}
```

Comment: see also `?reformulate`

Comment: Thanks for this lmo. Very helpful answer and works like a charm. Will also look into reformulate Ben. Thanks.